# Position relative in firefox causing problems with google-map-markers clickable area

Tags: css, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3, css-position

The clickable area around a google-map-marker is shifting/misplaced when text (or other content) is added before the map-div. 
It is working fine in chrome, ie etc. - only firefox seems to cause this problem (as far as I can see). 
When - in web-console - changing map-div's elementstyle from 'relative' to 'static' the problem is gone.

The code below is borrowed from googles map-examples - if I uncomment the lorem-text the map-markers clickable area is moving/misplaced. Any suggestions on how to solve the problem (if there is a problem - I might have missed something obvious):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex icons</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas
        {
            height: 800px;
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2)
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                          mapOptions);

            setMarkers(map, beaches);
        }

        var beaches = [
          ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
          ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
          ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
          ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
          ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];

        function setMarkers(map, locations) {
            var image = {
                url: 'https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/geo/cdate/art/dots/blue_dot.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(21, 21),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10)  
            };

            var shape = {
                coords: [0,0, 0,21, 21,21, 21,0],
                type: 'poly'
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var beach = locations[i];
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    shape: shape,
                    title: beach[0]
                });
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!--<p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p>-->

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### UPDATE

This bug was handled in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826867 and fixed in version 3.21 of API in September 2015.

Comment: A bug? In Firefox? Or ... ? It's driving me crazy - tried different things but nothing seems to solve the problem. Please help - just copy the code above, place it in a html-doc ... then try with and without the lorem-text uncommented. With the lorem-text above the map, you should see how the markers clickable area is moving away from the marker (it looks like the marker is no longer clickable). If you have a suggestion to how to solve the problem (if there is a problem - maybe I just miss something obvious), you'll get a huge virtual hug from me - I would really be grateful, thanks :-)

Comment: What version of Firefox?  There is an accepted issue in the issue tracker on FF 39.0 [Issue 8278: Bug: Polylines created using DrawingManager doesn't follow correctly mouse cursor in Firefox 39](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278)

Comment: I'm using newest/v. 39.0 ... thanks a lot. Will immediately check it ...

Comment: It seems like a bug in the map vs FF 39 ... regarding this https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278 ... THNX geocodezip ... :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the js src from v=3.exp to v=3

Comment: YES! That solved the problem. In my own project I was linking to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false - and it was causing the problem - like in the html-example above (linking to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true). 
But linking to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=true solved the problem in both examples. THNX :-)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the version as v=3 ensure that you have the most recent release version. The current release version is 3.20. The problem arises with the experimental version, currently 3.21, which is the default default version if you do not explicitly specify a version using the v parameter.