# Google Maps markers shifted only in Firefox if CSS margin property for map canvas is set

Tags: css, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

The clickable (or "catchment" area) for markers on Google Maps seem to be incorrectly shifted if `<div>` holding the map canvas is styled with CSS `margin` property different than `0px`.

Smallest working example with the incorrect location of marker area designated with red circle (the title "marker" should appear around the circle):

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.0, 17.0);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'marker'
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map-canvas {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  #position {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
    left: 140px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px dashed #f00;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="position"></div>
```

Working example also on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n6ccz1n0/

The issue detected on Firefox 39.0 (Chrome and Internet Explorer render it properly).

It might be an issue related to the one described here:
[Position relative in firefox causing problems with google-map-markers clickable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298920/position-relative-in-firefox-causing-problems-with-google-map-markers-clickable)

Comment: Is it possibly related to this:  [Issue 8278: Bug: Polylines created using DrawingManager doesn't follow correctly mouse cursor in Firefox 39](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278)

Comment: I am not sure your `position` is where it should be. It is `fixed`, which puts it in relation to the parent object, `body`. However, the marker is offset by roughly 30x30 pixels (which is the `margin` of the map). I am not sure what is wrong, and I cannot diagnose for you.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for pointing out this bug, it's apparently the same - Google Maps related - issue as in described case.
@bcdan - The `position` property was used here only to prompt where to look for the incorrectly shifted clickable area.

Comment: As followup, it has been reported and can be confirmed that implicitly adding `v=3` to `<script src=` URL param when calling Google Maps API makes the code working correctly in Firefox 39.0.

Comment: Can confirm. Had this issue in F39 only. Solved using v=3 in the maps script.

Comment: if this solves your issue. it would be better to provide the solution as an answer